# Can not change original file name,Compiler Error Message: CS0433:

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

It's a little bit complicated.I got a .net class library project form someone else and added it in my solution referenced by a asp.net mvc project. For some reason I changed the project name form "abc" to "xyz" and also Assembly name, Default namespace name in project properties page. I could build the solution and get the xyz.dll in the bin folder.
The problem is I can't run the web application because of the error "Compiler Error Message: CS0433:". I looked into the folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\" and found out the abc.dll still there and I checked the file detail information on properties page. The file description and product name are the same xyz, but the original filename is still abc.dll. I really don't know what's going on here.
I wish some could help me out,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete abc.dll from the root directory and then recheck it. Because IIS configure with this file and after changing it will not rebuild with this files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename it in a file explorer or using Visual studio? Check the .csproj file and the .sln file and make sure all references in there reflect the new names. Also, check your dependencies and references to make sure they point at the new dll, and not the old one

Comment: I had created a new project just copied the code files but bin, obj, properties folders and *.csproj.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have figure it out but for other peoples who might search for the solution.
Right click on your solution or project file ->  Click on properties ->  And then there is first tab with name application Click on that. You will find two text box one for Assembly Name (Change this to xyz).
see attached image.[properties dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OKb4.png)